# Why $ b =1 $ solves the contradiction in this proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The proof is given below:

> **Theorem 3.3 (Pythagoras).** The number $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.
>
> ***Proof.*** Suppose, to the contrary, that $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number, say $\sqrt{2}=a/b$, where $a$ and $b$ are both integers with
>   $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Squaring, we get $a^2=2b^2$, so that $b\mid a^2$. If
>   $b>1$, then the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic guarantees the
>   existence of a prime $p$ such that $p\mid b$. It follows that $p\mid
> > a^2$ and, by Theorem 3.1, that $p\mid a$; hence, $\gcd(a,b)\geq p$. We
>   therefore arrive at a contradiction, unless $b=1$. But if this
>   happens, then $a^2=1$, which is impossible (we assume that the reader
>   is willing to grant that no integer can be multiplied by itself to
>   give $2$). Our supposition that $\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number is
>   untenable, and so $\sqrt{2}$ must be irrational.

[(Image that replaced text).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNy5u.png)

But I do not understand why $ b =1 $ solves the contradiction in this proof. Could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: wlog $b > 0$. The proof deduces a contradiction in both cases $b > 1$ and $b = 1$, which are the only possible values of $b$

Comment: I am speaking about the fourth line from below, the writer said "we therefore arrive at a contradiction, unless $b = 1$" ..... why he said in this sentence that no contradiction occurs if $b = 1$ @BillDubuque

Comment: Which means $\,b > 1\,$ yields a contradiction, so we are left  to consider the remaining case $\,b = 1,\,$ which they proceed to show also yields a contradiction.

Comment: got it @BillDubuque thanks!

Comment: Great! We can eliminate the first use of contradicition: $\gcd(b,a)=1,\ b\mid a\color{#c00}a\,\Rightarrow\,b\mid\color{#c00}a\,$ by Euclid's Lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a^2 = 1$, then $a = 1$ or $a = -1$. In the latter case, $b$ would also need to be negative for their ratio to be positive; so, let us pursue the former case without loss of generality.

If $a=1$, then we would have $1/b = \sqrt{2}$ for some positive integer $b$. But, squaring both sides would then yield that $1/b^2 = 2$, i.e., $b^2 = 1/2$. Since $b$ is a positive integer, we have that $b \geq 1$ hence $b^2 \geq 1$, from which we conclude that it cannot be the case that $b^2 = 1/2$, for $1/2 \not\geq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

With $$a^2=2b^2$$ and $$b=1$$ the contradiction is $$a^2=2$$ which says there is an integer whose square is $2$ and apparently we do not accept that, hence a contradiction.